# why im not able to redirect the given url from my Webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri("www.google.com");
            return response;
        }
```

Here why im not able to redirect To that Url
Thank u

Comment: This is a web api?  APIs normally return data in say json format.  Anyone calling your API is not going to be able to understand a redirect to google.com

Comment: @DaImTo Do u have any idea how can i redirect to google from my Api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
new Uri("www.google.com")
```

throws an `System.UriFormatException` becase no scheme is specified. Just add scheme and it will work

```
new Uri("http://www.google.com")
```